# Is there a way to use the RMAH if all you have is a pay-as-you-go phone?

Tags: diablo-iii

We have pay-as-you-go regular cell phones (no data plan or contract, no smartphones or tablets or land line).  Diablo will not allow us to use our phone numbers when we try to sign up to be able to use the RMAH.  Is there anything we can do to legitimately participate in that part of the game without having to change phones and carriers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get an authenticator without a smartphone and without paying?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73729/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-authenticator-without-a-smartphone-and-without-paying)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. You don't need an authenticator to use the RMAH unless you want it to go to your battle.net balance.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to use the RMAH, once via PayPal (which needs SMS Authentication) or via Battle.net Balance which only works if you have an authenticator attached to your account. So since you can't use your mobile to use SMS authentication you are left with Battle.net balance and an authenticator attached to your account.
Here you have 2 options:

1. Physical authenticator ([Link](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/battle-net-authenticator-faq))
2. Mobile authenticator ([Link](http://eu.battle.net/support/en/article/battle-net-mobile-authenticator-faq))

[Battle.net Balance FAQ](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/battle-net-balance-frequently-asked-questions-faq).

Comment: yup, the only reason you need to hook up the SMS is if you ever want to sell an item and have it go straight to PayPal

Comment: Using Paypal is what I would like to do, but Blizz won't take the phone number I have.  I'm not sure if the WinAuth recommendation applies because it's not the authenticator step I'm hung up at, it's needing a "valid" phone number for Blizz to text...  prepaid/pay-as-you-go phones aren't recognized by them.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to offer a suggestion to use [winauth](http://code.google.com/p/winauth/). It's a very useful application. I can also attest that it works fine for people without a smartphone. I passed this website to my friend who like you has a dumb phone and has no problem using it for his account.

The other thing that I find useful.I have the authenticator on my android smart phone, but sometimes I'll leave my phone upstairs in my house or charging somewhere in another room. Once I changed the serial and authenticator code to match my phone. I now can always pull it up on my computer if needed. Also includes a handy send to clipboard function if you are logging in via a browser. There are also options to encode the serial and put a password on the application if you would like as well. Overall a very useful program.

The other useful thing I want to comment on as well is you can write down your serial code for your authenticator and if you are ever in a spot where you don't have you authenticator on you, you can download the application and get your key as long as you have that serial code (saved somewhere securely I hope).

Comment: So using another authenticator and a Battle.net balance is the only option, or would winauth make using Paypal possible?

Comment: In the eyes of Blizzard winauth and the Blizzard mobile authenticator are the same thing. You would be able to use PayPal just fine with it.

Comment: But to my understanding PayPal does rely on SMS authentification and works without the Battle.net authenticator.

Comment: Still trying to figure out how to get to use Paypal with the RMAH when Blizzard will not recognize my phone number...